# Inserting elements in a QSet<QString> and retrieving , removing the last item of the QSet

Tags: c++, qt, data-structures

I have the following dataset:

```
 QSet<QString> set;
```

I tried to insert 3 elements to the QSet.

```
set.insert("A");
set.insert("B");
set.insert("C");
```

After adding the above three elements,its showing the size of my `QSet` as 3, but total 16 elements are visible,among which 13 elements are being shown as Empty.
And every time,I  try to debug this, the element "A" is on the top of the list once and next time, "C" appears on the top of the list.

Due to this, I am not able to retrieve the last element of the `QSet. I want to retrieve the element,which is inserted at the last to the`QSet.

I Am using the following lines of code,for retrieving and removing the elements from `QSet`.

```
QString str1 = QString( *( set.end() - 1 ) ); //to get the last element

set.remove( *( set.end() - 1 ) ); //to remove the last element
```

I think,it has to do something with properly initializing my `QSet`, but I still could not figure out the problem exactly

I would be glad if someone can explain me better
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "16 elements are visible"? Where do you see these?

Comment: @Thomas: While debugging, I had a look at my QSet, it was displaying like this:  [0] emtpy, [1] empty,...., [2] "C",....[5] "A",......., [12] "B",....[16] Empty. Hope you understood

Comment: @Math_Enthusiast, probably you insert in your set something else too or it wasn't initially empty?

Answer (score 1):

`QSet` does not store it's elements in any particular order. As you have noticed, the *no particular order* is not even stable between runs of your program. In a very real sense, there *is not* a "last element", which is why there is no `front` or `back` member

The order of insertion is not recorded anywhere. If you want to maintain the insertion order, you will need a [SequenceContainer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/SequenceContainer), such as `std::vector` or `QVector`.

Answer (score 0):

QSet is based on Hash table and so unordered. Use QMap, if you need ordering by key.

Comment: Then, I think, it is better to use QList right? Because,I just want to retrieve last element and then also remove the last element from the list. By, last element,I mean, newly added element in the list.

Comment: In that case, QVector should be the choice as it gives better performance than QList and it always stores elements sequentially in memory. append on QVector is relatively fast and it typically allocates more memory than needed. So, it can grow without reallocating entire vector each time.

Comment: ah great.So,I will use QVector now. Is there any way to add only Different elements in QVector? I mean,if I have an element called "X" in my QVector.If I try to add "X" again, it is added again.Is there any way to ignore such cases,if element already exists? Any effective way?

Comment: Well if you prefer not to have duplicate entries then I would suggest to use QMap. It allows only one value per key, if you insert an element with already existing key then previous value will be erased.